# Convergence of expression involving normal c.d.f.

Tags: probability-theory, numerical-methods

I have derived the following expression for the error of some approximation: for any $\epsilon > 0$

> $|u_{precise} - u_{approx}| \leq C_1 \epsilon + C_2 \cdot \Phi \left ( -\sqrt{-2 \ln (\sqrt{2\pi} \gamma \epsilon) } \right )$,

where $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ and $\Phi$ is the c.d.f. of the standard normal.

I would like to estimate the speed of convergence of the second component in the expression to $0$ w.r.t. $\epsilon$ or at least to clarify whether it is faster or slower than linear convergence. I tried to play around with the Taylor expansion of $\Phi$, but it didn't lead to any sensible result, so any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these inequalities $$(x^{-1}-x^{-3})\exp(-x^2/2)\leq 1-\Phi(x) \leq x^{-1}\exp(-x^2/2)$$ for $x>0$.